# UWP FolderPicker - show the dialog window centered over parent

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

In a button click handler I am showing a **FolderPicker** dialog using the following piece of code:

```
 var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();            
 folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
 folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
 StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

The dialog window is shown in the upper left corner of the screen. I would like the window to appear centered over the parent window. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> show the dialog window centered over parent

Currently, UWP `FolderPicker` does not provide api that specific the dialog window's location, And FolderPicker was handled by [Runtime broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#how-pickers-work) that is system level, in other words, the dialog will set it's location base on the uwp app window's position. If you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app.